# HTML form works on desktop but not mobile

Tags: php, html, ios, mysql, mobile

I have an HTML form to send a small 20 character message to a MySQL table. It works wonderfully on my desktop while running Firefox 49 but on my friend's IPhone with IOS 9.3.3 and using the Safari browser it dose not work at all. I've spent a few hours googling to try and find the cause of the issue. Anyway here is my code:

Form things:

```
<iframe id="target-frame" name="target-frame"></iframe>
<form id="mark-form" target="target-frame" action="make_mark.php" method="post">
    You have 20 characters, use them wisely. <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Mark" onclick="timeoutMark()"></input>
    <input type="text" name="mark" maxlength="20"></input>
</form>

<script>
var timeoutMark = function timeoutMark() {
    setTimeout(markForm, 5);
}
var markForm = function markForm() {
    document.getElementById('mark-form').reset();
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

make_mark.php:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/paths.php");
include($path['mysql']);
$mark = db_quote($_POST['mark']);
$ip = db_quote($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo "<textarea>".$mark."</textarea>";

if ($mark == "''") {
    exit("Mark is empty");
}
$query = db_query("INSERT INTO marks (mark, ip) VALUES (" . $mark . "," . $ip . ")");
```

Comment: as i am checking above code should work in mobile browser as well but might be there some mis-configuration in browser setting hence it wont be refresh after each 5 minute or something like that

Comment: Run the same thing on Safari, I am pretty sure there also the issue exists.

Comment: Yea I meant to say that the browser in which it was broken was Safari, I edited the question to say that.